# max returns negative infinity in R

Tags: r, infinity

I have stumbled upon a seemingly simple problem which I just cannot solve.  I am attempting to use `max` and `which` on a `vector` that does not contain the value of interest.  Ideally I would like to obtain the number `0` in that instance.  But I keep getting negative infinity.

```
ff <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
my.index <- 1
max(which(ff == my.index))
#[1] -Inf
#Warning message:
#In max(which(ff == my.index)) :
#  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Here are some other attempts that return the same result:

```
max(as.numeric(which(ff == my.index)))
max(which(ff == my.index), na.rm = TRUE)
max(as.numeric(which(ff == my.index)), na.rm = TRUE)
max(numeric(0))
```

I did notice:

```
max(0)
[1] 0
```

So, I thought maybe the simplest solution would be to convert `-Inf` to `0`.  Is there a more elegant `base R` solution than the one below?  A one-liner?  Ideally one that would not return a `warning` message?

```
aaa <- max(which(ff == my.index))
aaa[is.infinite(aaa)] <- 0
aaa
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max` uses *all* values in all arguments passed to `max(...)`, so:

```
max(which(ff == my.index), 0)
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

On how to do it, thelatemail has already given you an answer, just pass an extra default value as an argument. But I would add the reason why you are getting `-Inf`.

Since there are no elements in `ff` with a value of 1, `which(ff == my.index)` returns `integer(0)` which is not the same as `0`. It is an empty object of class `integer`.

Since any integer is the greatest in a set which contains only that integer it makes sense to consider that the `max` function returns `-Inf` since if you have two sets (vectors in R) **A** and **B**, `max(A, B) = max(max(A), max(B))`. So if **A** is empty and **B** is not, `max(A,B) = max(B)`, but this was equal to `max(max(A), max(B))`, which implies that `max(B) > max(A)` for any integer, so in order to follow this R assigns the value of `-Inf` to `max(integer(0))`.